# Running software in another X session

Tags: xorg, firefox, vnc

I am testing the [Firefox nightly builds](http://nightly.mozilla.org). On occation, the nightly builds crashes X.

Is it possible to start a separate X session to run the crashing program in? Does `vncserver` run its own X session? If so, it would probably solve my problem if I ran the nightly firefox in a VNC server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would've said you should do it like this:

```
sudo Xnest :1.0 -geometry 800x480 -ac & DISPLAY=:1.0 chromium-browser
```

This comes without the benefit of a window manager. To get one, you could replace the above 'chromium-browser' with `x-window-manager` or something similar.

Append an ampersand to the command to get back to the terminal after the command has started to execute. You can then start applications in the nested x server by prefixing them with `DISPLAY=:1.0`

But: this seems to be broken somehow. There is a [Bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/296122) (Status: in progress; Importance: High) related to it, I’ve tested it and, indeed, it reliably crashes when i try to start "x-window-manager" or "gnome-session".

The above command however, without a window manager, runs fine (at least with chromium, please report if it works with firefox 4)

Comment: Thanks for the Xnest tip. I was not aware of Xnest.